# Generate Message that internet is not connected or enabled

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

In my application, i call WebServices and getting GPRS values. The problem is that when internet is not connected my application generate message of "Force Close". Kindly guide me, How it generate message that internet is not available or Please connect internet and it doesn't generate message of Force Close. Thanks for help

Kindly guide me for Mobile network too. that if it is not ON my application generate message that please On mobile network. How it is Possible???

Thanks for Kittu & ram Kiran help:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() 
{
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) 
    {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;

}
```

call this method whenever you are trying to call the webservice

```
if(haveNetworkConnection())
{
    // call the webservice
}
```

add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`
permission in manifest

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
//check connection
        public boolean isOnline() {
            ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

                return true;
            }

          //alert box to show internet connection error
            AlertDialog.Builder Internet_Alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(DinnerDenActivity.this);
            // set title
            Internet_Alert.setTitle("Attention!");
            Internet_Alert.setMessage("This application requires internet connectivity, no internet connection detected");
            Internet_Alert.setPositiveButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    onQuitPressed(); 
                }
            });

            Internet_Alert.create().show();
            return false;
        }
```

**isOnline** checks for internet connectivity

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This permission should be added in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a broadcast receiver like this

```
public class NetworkBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
     * android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean isNetworkDown= intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        if(isNetworkDown){
            ApplicationInfo.networkAvailable = false;
        }else{
            ApplicationInfo.networkAvailable = true;
        }
    }

}
```

And before calling your web service you can check for `ApplicationInfo.networkAvailable` like this

```
if(!ApplicationInfo.networkAvailable){
    //show msg -> no network connectivity
}else{
    //proceed with WS call
}
```

Register your receiver for `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`. This can be done in code and in AndroidManifest file

Comment: thank you for help. kindly guide me how to generate message that please on mobile network for sending updates

Comment: i did not get it. Can u please rephrase

Comment: I want that in my application when i click on my application it generate message that "please On mobile network" if mobile network is not ON.

Comment: use the broadcast receiver to set the flag. and in your activity where you want to show the message, check for this flag and show message using a dialog/alert dialog/pop up window.